# JavaScript: get object instances to contain extended variables

Tags: javascript, object, instances, extending

So, say I had the following script:

```
var hey = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3,
    init: function(newFoo){
        this.foo = newFoo;
        return this;
    }
}
hey.check = function(){
    alert('yeah, new function');
}
```

Basically, I can call `new hey.init(999)` and get a new `hey` variable with `hey.foo` set to 999. But when I do that, `hey.init(999).check()` is no longer defined. Is there a way to mimic the script, but allow new `hey`'s to have the extended variables/functions?

EDIT: changed `hey.check()` to `hey.init(999).check()`
sorry about that...

Comment: your `hey` is an object, not a class that you can instantiate object from, I edited my answer below with the syntax I believe you wanted to code.

Comment: seems to be working..maybe the problem is someplace else or the question needs to be rephrased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not actually getting a new `hey` instance, but a `hey.init` instance, which only contains `foo` property.

I think this is what are you trying to do:

```
var hey =function() {
    this.foo = 1;
    this.bar = 2;
    this.baz = 3;
    this.init = function(newFoo){
        this.foo = newFoo;
    }
}
hey.check = function(){
    alert('yeah, new function');
}


//now instantiating our class, and creating an object:
var heyInstance=new hey();
heyInstance.init(999);
alert(heyInstance.foo);
```

Comment: Interesting. So, if I wanted to return the `hey` instance after running `init`, I can't just `return this`, because `this` would refer to `init`. How would I return the parent `this` of init?

Comment: Actually, you can do `return this;` and `this` will be referring to `heyInstance`. but when you did `new hey.init()` in your sample code, that `this` was referring to `hey.init` instance, since then what you instantiated was `hey.init` and not `hey`

Comment: Okay, so I just ran a quick test with your code and `heyInstance.check()` is undefined. I guess it has to be `hey.prototype.check` instead of `hey.check`. But is `hey.prototype` cross browser compatible? Say, IE6 and FF2?

Comment: Yes, `hey.prototype` is cross browser, it's a JavaScript core syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me...

When I paste

```
var hey = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3,
    init: function(newFoo){
        this.foo = newFoo;
        return this;
    }
}
hey.check = function(){
    alert('yeah, new function');
}
console.log(hey);
hey.init(22);
console.log(hey);
hey.check();
```

into Firebug's console, I end up with an alert from `hey.check();` and the second log shows an object where `foo == 22`.

What's not working on your end?